# Asp.Net Core 2.2 Docker HTTPS issue

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have a problem when I'd like to run my app (Asp.Net Core 2.2) under a docker.

Firstly, I created a self-signed certificate using:

> `dotnet dev-certs https -v -ep d:\temp\cert-aspnetcore.pfx -p ufo`

after that, I copied to cert-aspnetcore.pfx  to C:\Users\MyUsername.aspnet\https location

Here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  testapi.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}testapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: TestApi.Api/Dockerfile
```

and docker-compose.override.yml

```
> version: '3.4'
> 
> services:   testapi.api:
>     environment:
>       - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
>       - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
>       - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44395
>       - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=ufo
>       - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/root/.aspnet/https/cert-aspnetcore.pfx
>     ports:
>       - "9000:80"
>       - "44395:443"
>     volumes:
>       - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
>       - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
```

But when I try to run docker-compose up --build I get:

> crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0] Unable to start Kestrel.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint.
>   No server certificate was specified, and the default developer
>   certificate could not be found.

If you need any information please let me know. Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried overriding the default entrypoint/command for the container with something like tail -f /dev/null in order for the container not to be destroyed and then running a shell on the container to see if the folder structure is correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you didn't accept created certificate.

And can you try to run this code line on cmd or powershell ?

**dotnet dev-certs https --trust**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-3.0